# Eigenvalues of $i x^3$ potential

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

There is a famous [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.5243) by Carl Bender et al., where they investigated a class of non-Hermitian potentials and showed their spectrum is entirely real. One such a case is $i x^3$ potential. I would like to verify this. So:

```
V[x_] := I x^3
H = -u''[x] + V[x]*u[x];

{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[H, u[x], {x, -3, 3}, 10, Method -> 
{"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
```

now, vals returns not entirely real spectrum, for exmaple, $9.09357 + 4.38307 i$.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The eigenvalues seem to come as  complex conjugate pairs: may be a clue?

Comment: @chris It shouldn't! The spectrum must be real. Thousand papers claim this, I posted the first paper initiating the study of these kinds of potentials.

Comment: Never use upper-case letters to start the names of variables as they can conflict with system names.

Comment: For what boundary condition?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks for letting me know this.

Comment: @chris The boundary condition is simply on the real axis, i.e., the wave functions should vanish at infinity on the $x$-axis.

Comment: it seems the funs[[4]][-x] ===funs[[5]] [x]; it also seems that NDEigensystem does the job in as much that funs are indeed eigenfunctions of the equation: `{ReImPlot[vals[[4]] funs[[4]], {x, -3, 3}],
  ReImPlot[-D[funs[[4]], x, x] + V[x] funs[[4]] // Evaluate, {x, -3, 
    3}, PlotStyle -> Red]} // Show
`

Comment: @chris Interesting observation.

Comment: @chris In 1980's J. Zinn-Justin showed this reality also for $i \phi^3$ field theory, numerically; which, I cannot find the paper now. But I had always taken this as granted!

Comment: The boundary conditions are not that simple.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0703096.pdf

Comment: @chuy For what potential? Carl has considered the so-called Stokes' wedges for other potentials such as $-x^4$, but $i x^3$ should be on the real axis.

Comment: Look at eq (24), (25), and (26) in the linked paper.

Comment: @chuy I had reviewed this paper before its publication, the analytical part. When epsilon is between $-1$ and $2$ the wedges (correct boundary conditions) contain the real axis. In the case which I have mentioned in my post, epsilon is $1$.

Comment: Oh yes I see, it will converge faster if go along the middle of the wedges, but still with your case the real line is in the wedge. But your box is too small. As you increase the box size you will see the eigenvalues converge to real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You would like to verify analytical result numerically. The accuracy can be improved up to a point by increasing the interval. Consider:

```
k = 10;
{vals[k], funs[k]} = NDEigensystem[H, u[x], {x, -k, k}, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
vals[k]
(*{1.15627 + 2.07576*10^-13 I, 4.10923 + 7.61373*10^-13 I, 
 7.56227 + 1.03414*10^-11 I, 11.3144 - 4.32842*10^-11 I, 
 15.2916 - 3.66594*10^-10 I, 19.4515 + 2.90755*10^-10 I, 
 23.7667 + 1.17557*10^-8 I, 28.2175 - 8.95289*10^-8 I, 
 32.7889 + 0.000137561 I, 37.6183 - 0.192629 I}*)

k = 30;
{vals[k], funs[k]} = NDEigensystem[H, u[x], {x, -k, k}, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}}}];
vals[k]

(*{1.15627 - 9.73242*10^-14 I, 4.10923 + 3.34135*10^-13 I, 
 7.56227 - 4.76813*10^-12 I, 11.3144 + 6.64141*10^-12 I, 
 15.2916 - 4.67567*10^-11 I, 19.4515 + 7.56256*10^-11 I, 
 23.7667 - 1.78818*10^-9 I, 28.2175 + 4.39571*10^-8 I, 
 32.7891 + 0.0000294119 I, 37.3791 - 0.0750528 I}*)

k = 300;
{vals[k], funs[k]} = NDEigensystem[H, u[x], {x, -k, k}, 10, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.02}}}}];
vals[k]

(*{1.15627 - 2.10303*10^-14 I, 4.10923 + 8.50548*10^-14 I, 
 7.56227 - 1.34412*10^-12 I, 11.3144 + 8.30768*10^-12 I, 
 15.2916 + 9.77016*10^-12 I, 19.4515 - 3.40284*10^-10 I, 
 23.7667 + 3.24796*10^-9 I, 28.2175 - 1.97439*10^-8 I, 
 32.7891 - 0.0000618235 I, 37.4576 + 0.160385 I}*)
```

Now look at the plot

```
ListLinePlot[{{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ vals[10],
  {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ vals[30],
  {Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ vals[300]
  }, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome"}, 
 AxesStyle -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Only the 10th eigenvalue is a bit problematic.